# How to remove button extensions in vaadin?

Tags: java, button, vaadin7

```
        downloadButton.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent event) {

           // if (downloadButton.getExtensions().size() > 0) {
           //    downloadButton.getExtensions().clear();
          //  }

            tmpFileErzeuger.erzeugeXMLDatei(selectedItems);

            FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(tmpFileErzeuger.addToZipFile());

            FileDownloader fileDownloader = new FileDownloader(fileResource);
            fileDownloader.extend(downloadButton);

        }
    });
```

Following code creats an XML file, compress (zip) (each zip file has a new file name) and finally downloads it to the computer. But each time I change someting and press the button to make the program do all these steps in order to create a new zip file,  I  get the old file and the new created zip file together. I actually dont want to keep the old one, only the newly created file.
Has anybody an idea what should be changed?

Comment: I didn't work with the `FileDownloader` so far but I can imagine that adding it multiple times might be not what you want. Try derive `FileDownloader` and override `getFileDownloadResource`. Or, what does your "addToZipFile" do exactly?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: No I am looking for a solution :( . I think fileDownloader.extend(); is not compatible with Firefox. In Internetexplorer I get only the last created zip file. And to your question addToZipFile() create for me a .zip file.

Comment: I found that link from vaadin forum https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/2581494/2581493 . But I can't use this. I want to download from a table the selected row.

Comment: Did you try my proposal? Try derive FileDownloader and override getFileDownloadResource and do **not** extend the download button more than once (not on each click but on creation once).

Comment: Yes I tried your proposal. But there is a problem. At the beginning I have no resource. FileDownloader wants a resource in constructor. If I select a row then I have a resource.

Comment: Ok, then you should add the FileDownloader on the first hit of the download button and later only exchange the file resource in it. According to this [page](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Letting+the+user+download+a+file) usually you create the button and extend it with the `FileDownloader`. Why do you need to change the download file contents on click?

Comment: I have Table.If I select a row it gives me a personal number then I call with this personal number from my database all relations from the tables. Then I make a xml file then compress it in a zip file. Each download is a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
  FileDownloader f = new FileDownloader(new StreamResource(null, null)) {
        @Override public Resource getFileDownloadResource() {
             tmpFileErzeuger.erzeugeXMLDatei(selectedItems);
             return new FileResource(tmpFileErzeuger.addToZipFile());        
        }
    };

    f.extend(downloadButton);
```

I think this solution is ok!

Comment: If you have any suggestion. We can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling "f.extend(downloadButton)", you must make sure to remove all the previous extensions of the component.

```
if (fileDownloader != null && downloadButton.getExtensions().contains(fileDownloader)) {
   downloadButton.removeExtension(fileDownloader);
}
```